# How to dockerize nestjs app in nx monorepo

Tags: docker, nest, nx-monorepo

I am working on Nx monorepo with several projects inside.
Now, I need to dockerize my nestjs app.

I am not sure how to create Docker file inside the 'backend' folder ( my nestjs app ), to be executed as expected.

Normally I am starting the app using this command: `yarn run nx backend:serve`
But this doesn't work on the docker. It says that `command nx backend:serve is not found`.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:20.9.0-alpine3.18

WORKDIR /src

RUN npm add --global nx@latest

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json from the root of the build context
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN yarn  

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run the application
CMD [ "yarn", "run","nx backend:serve" ]
```